# Is there a way to use a PC to create a file that will execute on a Mac?

Tags: python, windows, macos, executable

On my PC, I have:

1. A Python script.
2. A .json file that the script needs in order to run.
3. A directory I made using PyInstaller that includes an .exe file, which runs the script.

My goal is to enable a Mac user to do the equivalent of what a PC user can do with the .exe file: run the script as simply as possible, without needing to install Python or otherwise have any programming familiarity. Ideally, I'd love to be able to send the user a single file, and all they have to do is run it.

Is there a way I can implement that using my PC?

P.S.: I hope I'm not breaching etiquette by posting about this issue twice in one day; if I am, I apologize and I hope someone will kindly clue me in. I had posted a similar question, and based on the replies, I've realized that what I was trying to do before is not possible and have revised my question accordingly.

Comment: simplest solution would be to use a mac device and do exactly what you did in windows. create a package using pyinstaller, but in this case the resulting file will not be .exe but the one that will work on mac.

Comment: Thanks but my question is whether or not there's a way to do it on a PC :)

Comment: Just an rough idea, but shouldn't you be able to do pyinstaller with cross-compilation?  PyInstaller itself don't support cross-compiling from Windows to Mac directly, but you can set up a cross-compilation environment using tools like MinGW-w64 or MXE. These could allow you to compile Mac executables on your Windows PC.

Answer (score 0):

So what I would say you can do is making a bash file. Since Macs usually have some 3.x version of python preinstalled, it shouldn't be a problem running the file for beginners. The bash file could look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 path/to/file.py
```

Then name the file "your name".sh. Unfortunately, the file has to be run from the Mac terminal, and to make it double-click executable, the Mac user would have to type

```
chmod 755 path/to/file.sh
```

in their command line.

I have also tried using packages like py2exe and they can create a standalone .app or for windows a .exe file, but I cannot confirm, that it works on windows since I am using Mac.
Sadly I can't give you instructions on how to do it exactly, since it's been a while since I used it. If you need help though, I can look into it again.

Good Luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks! I'm a bit confused about the path, though. Am I supposed to be replacing "path/to/file.py" with the path of the file on my PC? If so, why?

Comment: This requires the user to have `python` installed

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga as I said in my answer, most Macs have python preinstalled.

Comment: @user765450 if both files are in the same folder for example, you can do "./yourfilename.py" 
Otherwise you have to use the complete file path from the users PC. That's why it's easier to put both files in one folder.